# Installing openvas ubuntu

Tags: kali-linux, ubuntu

Having problem installing openvas 7 on ubuntu 14.04.

Going by instructions on this [site](http://hackertarget.com/install-openvas-7-ubuntu/)
I have followed everything upto the third set of commands. At the fourth command openvas-mkcert, it says command not found.

How do i solve this ?

Comment: If the install makes path changes you'll need to open a new terminal, without more information its hard to know where the exact problem is.

Comment: @Ajaxasaur U were right, it works in a new terminal. Was hung at this for an hour. Thanks

Comment: woohoo! experience!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question.

The install process of openvas modifies the users PATH variable. The easiest solution to continue on is to open a new terminal (and close the one you did your first subset of work in). Once a new terminal is open return to your work and the openvas binaries should be found.

Alternatively you can run them directly from wherever it was installed to.

Example: $ /usr/share/openvas/bin/openvas-command  (whatever)